# Retrieving information from preexisting database on device

Tags: java, android, development-environment

I have already posted this question on android.stackexchange.com @wbogacz suggested this kind of question will be more welcomed on Overflow so I am asking here.

---

Suppose I have a database of the following form.

> ### Person id | Year of Birth | Salary
>
> ```
> P001  |    1978       | 94000
> P002  |    1989       | 67514
> P003  |    1991       | 97000
> :
> :
> P100  |    1981       | 78000
> ```

I want my app to be such that I should be able to choose to search in either of the fields available in the database.

A typical search is following.

> Search id "P067" in field "Person id"
>
> > This should display the details of "P067" as found in the database.

I have some amount of understanding of java (not full though). I am in the process of learning android, but I know python and logic of the programming.

So please list the things that I would need to understand before I could even begin to make this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml). It is a library to work with SQLite using Java Classes as Tables.
Check the samples on the homepage, it should give you a good head start.
Just ignore the part about creating a table/database and open your own instead.